# Exception in classes when using Django

Tags: python, django

I am not sure how can I catch an Exception in my django app.
I have a view, where I use my own class object which uses Requests framework to make remote API requests.
I need to catch Timeout exception inside my class code. When Timeout exception appears I need to return custom error page. My class code:

```
try:
    response = requests.request(
        method=method, url=self.url, auth=self.auth, timeout=3, verify=False, **kwargs
    )
except requests.Timeout:
    return HttpResponse('API connection timeout')
return response
```

However, in my django view code, I use something like:

```
user_details = auth_client['auth/users/%s/details' % (request.POST.get('username'))].get().json()['result']
```

so, when I try to return HttpResponse from class code, I get error:

```
'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I don't know how can I "omit" code from view and show HttpResponse directly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to return an HttpResponse in your requests class. Instead of catching the exception and replacing it with an unwanted HttpResponse, let it propagate and catch it in the view:

```
try:
    user_details = auth_client['auth/users/%s/details' % (request.POST.get('username'))].get().json()['result']
except requests.Timeout:
    return HttpResponse('whatever')
```

**Edit** OK, so here's another solution. You say that this is a class: so you can define a method, say `get_user_details`, which either returns the actual JSON, or none.

```
def get_user_details(username):
    try:
        user_details = self['auth/users/%s/details' % 'username'].get()
    except requests.Timeout:
        return []
    return user_details.json()['result']
```

so now in your view you just call `auth_client.get_user_details(request.POST['username'])`.

Comment: It may be a good solution, but in my views I use auth_client several times. It would be a pain to fix all occurences :(